# I have created Custom easing using js ? trying to run I am getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created Custom easing.after finally run the code i am getting error. please anybody help.

JS:

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'horizontal',
      useCSS: false,
      hideControlOnEnd: true,
      easing: 'easeOutElastic',
      speed: 2000
    });
```

Comment: Thank u @ Girish  for edit.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: infiniteLoop missing  error

Comment: Try to add infiniteLoop: false to your options.

Comment: thank u @ Flasz now working good.

Comment: thank u @Flasz,I want build one.

Comment: If you found it useful, please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add infiniteLoop: false to your options.